# I have to get two user input using two edittext and display anyone randomly in textview while button is clicked

Tags: java, android

I have doubt in Android that is, I have to get two user input using two edittext and print anyone randomly while button is clicked.

Comment: does my answer meet what you want?, if it does don't forget to accept it as an answer to your question :), it it doesn't explain more.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, if you want to learn Android, you're probably better off learning in Kotlin instead of Java: [Android’s Kotlin-first approach](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/first).  Personally, I'd rather spend my time on a cross-platform framework like [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/) or [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/), rather than deal with Kotlin.  But that's just me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use `Random` to draw. If it draws 0, it will show the result of the first input. If it is 1, it will show the result of the second input.

I deployed the application through `MainActivity` and `activity_main.xml`

**`MainActivity`**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText1;
    EditText editText2;
    TextView textView;
    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeView();

        button.setOnClickListener(this::onClick);
    }

    private void initializeView() {
        editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    private void onClick(View v) {
        Random random = new Random();
        EditText editText;

        if (random.nextInt(2) == 0) editText = editText1;
        else editText = editText2;

        textView.setText(editText.getText());
    }
}
```

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Input 1"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Input 2"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.842"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Click"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

since your request is vague somehow,

I assumed you're running the code somewhere in an activity, so I used findViewById to get the textView, 2 EditText and the button.

as for the random thing, I'm getting a random float and round it, if the float was >0.5 then rounding returns 1 and will show contents of first edit text otherwise I will show contents of second edit text.

and to make it run when the button is clicked, you should set an OnClickListener.

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
            EditText editText1 = findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
            EditText editText2 = findViewById(R.id.edittext2);

            Random rand = new Random();
            int which = Math.round(rand.nextFloat()) ;
            if(which ==1)textView.setText(editText1.getText().toString());
            else textView.setText(editText2.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```